# Trocar foreach por for

Tags: c#, foreach

Preciso trocar o seguinte `foreach()` por um `for()`. O problema é que ao invés de arrays o laço percorre um dicionario. 
Este é o código que quero transformar um `for()`:

```
foreach (var joint in body.Joints.Values)  //transformar em um for para usar valoren anteriores
{
  eixoX = joint.Position.X.ToString();
  eixoX = eixoX.Replace(",", ".");
  line.Append(eixoX + ",");

  eixoY = joint.Position.Y.ToString();
  eixoY = eixoY.Replace(",", ".");
  line.Append(eixoY + ",");
}
```

Por não dominar C# fiquei confuso para fazer isso.

Link para as implementacoes da [classe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.body.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você quer algo assim?

```
for (int index = 0; index < body.Joints.Count; index++) {
  var item = body.Joints.ElementAt(index);
  var jointType = item.Key;
  var joint = item.Value;
  //...
}
```

Comment: Eu não acho que isso vai ser um problema na prática, mas eu entendo que `.ElementAt(index)` em geral leva tempo O(index)? Não sei o que o `pmargreff` quer fazer, mas a possibilidade de criar um `List<T>` ou `T[]` temporário e usar esse objeto temporário talvez atenda melhor o que ele quer.

Comment: Funcionou, grato.

Comment: Achei legal a ideia da lista.

Answer (score 4):

Nao se devem usar ciclos `for` com um dicionário, porque o dicionário, por natureza, [nao está ordenado](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

> The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

Logo, tentar aceder a pares key-value do dicionário por indíce é uma **má prática**.

Se precisares de acesso às keys, usa um ciclo `foreach` sobre os *pares*, em vez de sobre os `Values`.

```
foreach (var pair in body.Joints)
{
    var x = pair.Key;
    var y = pair.Value;

}
```

Num comentário dizes que queres "usar valores anteriores". Como já expliquei, não existe o conceito de valor *anterior* num dicionário, porque não existe uma ordem definida. Se explicares melhor o que estás a tentar fazer, irei tentar ofercecer-te uma solução para o problema específico, que talvez seja usar um:

- [`OrderedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx);
- ou um [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx);
- ou uma simples `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`;
- ou algo completamente diferente.